# How can I make a change to a module without restarting python interpreter?

Tags: python

I am testing code in the python interpreter and editing in a separate window.  I currently need to restart python whenever I make a change to the module I am testing.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks,

Charlie

Comment: Duplicate: "How do I unload (reload) a Python module?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module

Answer (score 10):

The built-in function [`reload`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I think it is [importlib.reload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) now.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to reload the module, for which there is a [built-in function reload(module)](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload).  That said, when I looked it up just now (to make sure I had my reference right, Google returned a [couple of](http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/notes/reloading.html) [discussions](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2002-October/166262.html) (granted they are several years old) pointing out problems using reload().  You might want to review those if reload() causes you headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at IPython http://ipython.scipy.org. It has various features that make working with Python code interactively easier.

Some [screenshots](http://ipython.scipy.org/screenshots/index.html) and [tips](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/interactive/tutorial.html).